# Pandas to_datetime and datetime not equal for same date with same timezone

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

Am going bonkers over comparing two dates - one as pd_todatetime object and another as python datetime object. Both have same date and timezone, still on comparison it shows inequality. Below are two objects:

`Timestamp('2022-02-17 09:15:00+0530', tz='Asia/Kolkata')`

`datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 9, 15, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Kolkata' LMT+5:53:00 STD>)`

First one is pd.to_datetime index, while the latter is python datetime object.

Following is raw data:

```
from pytz import timezone

IST = timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
data = {'date': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 9, 15, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 19800)),  'open': 150,  'high': 203.75,  'low': 150,  'close': 191.45, 'volume': 185050,  'oi': 1735100}

df = pd.DataFrame(dat)

if df.date.dt.tz == None:
    df['date'] = df.date.dt.tz_localize(IST)
else:
    df['date'] = df.date.dt.tz_convert(IST)

df.set_index("date", inplace=True)
start = datetime(2022,2,17,9,15,0, tzinfo=IST)

if df.index.min() == start:
    do_something()
```

This is the place where the if statement is evaluated as False

Comment: Can you provide minimal code to create and compare the two objects? That might help.

Comment: show your source raw CSV input text and expected raw CSV output text. There will probably be other ways to do this which we can determine from the raw formats

Comment: Bill - kindly see the code snippet edited

Comment: If you use timezone objects from pytz, you **must** localize; e.g. `IST.localize(datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 9, 15))`. Otherwise, local mean time (LMT) is used - note the UTC offset of 5:53 hours in your example!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use `pandas.Timestamp`, like explained in:

> Timestamp is the pandas equivalent of python’s Datetime and is
> interchangeable with it in most cases. It’s the type used for the
> entries that make up a DatetimeIndex, and other timeseries oriented
> data structures in pandas.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html

Comment: Thank you pedro, I tried this, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used pytz before but I think I've replicated your issue:

```py
import pytz

a = pd.Timestamp('2022-02-17 09:15:00', tz='Asia/Kolkata')
b = datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 9, 15, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
assert(a == b)  # False
```

Note sure why these don't equal.  It might be related to [this note in the documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net).

Can you use the new built in [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html#module-zoneinfo) module (introduced in version Python 3.9)?

```
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

c = datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 9, 15, tzinfo=ZoneInfo('Asia/Kolkata'))
assert(a == c)  # True
```

Comment: Thanks Bill. It seems that working with pandas datetime and pythons datetime have serious issues. Certain things pandas datetime doesnt support hence need to use datetime.datetime. Its getting very painful to reconcile these two. Hopefully, pandas get better on this front

Comment: Note that pytz is a third party package.  Have a read of [PEP-615](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0615/). It explains a long-standing issue which I think might be at the heart of this. If someone with more datetime experience than me can comment that would be great. I rarely use timezones.

Comment: "*I've never used pytz before*" - well, see my comment under the question. You're repeating wrong code actually ;-) But `zoneinfo` is the better way to go anyways if you ask me; no such caveats there.

Comment: @FObersteiner great, thanks for explaining that. If someone doesn't have zoneinfo (Python 3.9) is there an alternative to using pytz? Can't they just use UTC offsets or something?

Comment: There's `backports.zoneinfo`, and also a depreciation shim for pytz, for legacy code